# How to increase the Admob match rate of my Android app?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, admob

I published an Android app built using Xamarin Forms. In the begins, my Admob did reach in mean 85% of match rate, but currently it has reached in mean ~50% (or less).

What can be the causes of this reduction? How we can increase the match rate?

Comment: you mean fill rate?

Comment: Sorry, the correct english term is "match rate", I will edit the question to fix.

Comment: That means that the users of your app does not click on the ad, so the platform decide to serve less of it to your app.

Comment: Then I can't do nothing in regards to this?

Comment: you could place it in another place, when users would be more likely to see it. Apart from that, really no.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much .. Do you know some official documentation describing this topic (specifically, match rate)?

Comment: Not really, but you could try google search for it :)
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6158845?hl=en